# Is this wireframe usable to view and add users ?

Tags: wireframe

This screen is to add users and view users. 
Please give me your feedbacks and let me know if you have any better ideas.

[image: Add and View multiple Users]

Comment: Consider the worst possible scenario that can occur in your system. How does this design cope? For example what are the maximum number of users? What happens when the list on the right becomes very long? What happens when users have same or similar names? Are the id's even names? What if you want to add all users? Should you be able to sort the users. What if you want to remove all users? Should you be able to search the users in the right hand list as well as the left? Is the right hand list sorted in the same way? Is removing the user you just added easy Might you want an undo? etc, etc...

Comment: I would say consider the most common scenario and design for that. Nail it for that.

Answer (score 1):

In order to play devils advocate I'm going to say "No". Of course it might be technical usable, but it could probably be better.

Adding people to a list is pretty much a solved problem on one of the most widely used technologies ever - email. There is probably a lot you can take from how good email client add allow you add email addresses to a emails. The main takeaway being that they don't have two lists - they have a single list that you add email to often using a type-ahead style predictive ui to help.

Two lists significantly increases the cognitive load required for a UI, users will have to hold four entities in their head: the list of people they want to add, the list of all users, the list users they have added and a comparison between the list of all users and the list of user already added.

I'd suggest exploring a design with a single list and a type-ahead style search input at the top.

(Of course if an comprehending overview of all available people is the most challenging part for your users a UI that places the focus on that would be more appropriate than my suggestion. But this is not normally the case.)

Answer (score 0):

It's usable. I have 130,000+ staff using Lotus Notes on a daily basis that still to this day baffles me at why anyone thought its UI was ***"best idea of the day"***...but despite my protest, its usable.

Humans are quick learners and will use even the crappiest experience we can throw at them (look at any SAP solution in the market today).

The question is in this case not "is it usable" but "is it efficient". To answer that "sure" if its repetitive, consistent and you visually control the way in which you're managing progressive disclosure here (ie i'm assuming you add a user and they then go into the list to the right, well you need to find a way now to make sure people can connect the dots that that flow just happened).

Back to efficiency. You could flip this problem around by leverage Search more strategically here.  In that you could firstly create ***Human Readable Search*** "***All*** users named **Sco***" which then creates a search result. The more the search gets refined the more the dataset gets reduced/increased. The point is you let them tweak the organic search instead of having to tick/untick their way through "who's in and who's out" which you can then later use as a "search set" that also would allow folks to be organically added if they get created outside this initial first-time experience "Oh we just hired Scott D yesterday, now i need to add him...oh..he already has been added"

This is one way to increase effeciency ... but are usable... but now we're really looking at the problem from "how can i manage users organically instead of statically"...

Note: Facebook kind of does this today with its search box...